# Excel - Conditional Formatting Based on Selection

Tags: excel, selection, conditional-formatting

Suppose that I have following data

[image: Initial Data]

I want to perform conditional formatting in cells containing `Y`. For example if I select the cell `Shirts` I want all the cells where `Shirts` is `Y` to be highlighted yellow. Similarly if I select cell `Books` I want all the cells where `Books` is `Y` to be highlighted green.

How can I achieve that?

**Expected Output (Shirts Output)**

[image]

Comment: Use conditional formatting based on a formula.

Comment: I've used formula but can't cells are not highlighted. If I select cell shirts the cells are not highlighting.

Comment: What "shirts"? cells don't have shirts...

Comment: Cell `B1` contains `Shirts`. When selecting `B1` I want to highlight cell `B2` and `B4` which contains `Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set some conditional formatting so if I enter "T" in one cell (Y3) then the selected cells (Y$:Y200) get formatted yellow with a border like so:

[image]

Just expand the formula to do what you need, perhaps and() to include "book" etc

```
And(y3="T",y4="Books")
```

as an example. Edit and test as you need.