# How can I colour cells based on 2 other cells matching?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, colors

So I'm trying to color my cells in grey for all the matching days not worked without using a formula (see attached picture). Thinking VBA is the only way to do this but unsure as to how? Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Did you try conditional formatting? and you probably should have a difference between [S]atruday and [S]unday or you will get false positives.

Comment: Hi, is there any reason that couldn't be tracked in the day of the week columns already setup to the right? Otherwise, I would just create another set of columns S,M,...,S and keep each persons "days not worked" in there. From there conditional formatting could be set up to shade the missed days gray in your original columns.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71880218/4961700

Comment: How would I use CF to accomplish that?

Comment: Each person would be working different days, so I would not be able to create another set of columns for each new person.

Comment: @J_albert it's not clear which cells you want to colour.   Please add another image showing, manually coloured to show what you want to achieve.   Also add the sampl5data _as text_ so we can copy paste it for testing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.